# SSRS2019 connecting to SQL Server is slow

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

We've set up several Windows Server 2022 machines for a new SSRS environment.

For the sake of this problem, let's says we have 2 servers:

- ServerA which hosts a SQL Server 2019 database containing data for the reports (on Windows Server 2022)
- ServerB which hosts SSRS 2019, as wel as SQL Server for the ReportServer databases

In SSRS, we've created some reports that use a datasource from a database on ServerA. All the reports load very slow. In the ExecutionLog, I find that TimeDataRetrieval is high (20 sec for simple queries).

Eventually I found out that it's setting up the connection that takes 20 seconds. When I create a new DataSource on the ReportServer to ServerA, and use the option "Using the following credentials", it takes 20 seconds before the "Test connection" button returns it succeeded (using Windows credentials). If I use "As the user viewing the report" (I went through all the trouble of setting up Kerberos delegation), it succeeds instantaneously from my client computer. Also if I select the option "Using the following credentials" and use a SQL Server account instead of Windows credentials, it's instant.

Both machines reside in the same network segment, so no firewalls in between.

I've  installed SSRS2019 on an "old" Windows Server 2019 machine. When I do the same thing there, it also succeeds instantaneously. I'm not sure if the OS is the reason, but the log file doesn't give me much information.

I've put on verbose logging for the SSRS service and this is the only thing I can see:

Slow connection test:
library!ReportServer_0-2!29c!03/29/2023-15:58:56:: i INFO: Call to TestConnectForDataSourceDefinitionAction(). User: .
dataextension!ReportServer_0-2!29c!03/29/2023-15:59:17:: i INFO: Opening SqlConnection with ClientConnectionId 0b4f8fa6049a49c0889867e89616c731

Fast connection test:
library!ReportServer_0-2!29c!03/29/2023-16:01:01:: i INFO: Call to TestConnectForDataSourceDefinitionAction(). User: .
dataextension!ReportServer_0-2!29c!03/29/2023-16:01:22:: i INFO: Opening SqlConnection with ClientConnectionId 933d75477ba646e68e7cd46dd7044760

I checked on ServerA and it takes 20 seconds before the connection is made. So it seems something is taking 20 seconds on ServerB before it actually starts connecting to SQL Server on ServerA.

I tried reinstalling but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

We have resolved this by doing the following:

- Create new machine with Windows Server 2019 -> install SQL and SSRS -> upgrade to Windows Server 2022.

If we do it in the following order, we still have the same issue:

- Create new machine with Windows Server 2019 -> upgrade to Windows Server 2022 -> install SQL and SSRS

We have tried to compare both servers in detail to figure out the exact reason behind the difference in behaviour, but we couldn't find it.